# Is it better to have more or less tables in sql?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a large database, one of the tables is called `Users`.

There are two kinds of users in the database - basic users, and advanced users. In the `users` table, there are 29 columns. However, only 12 of these are applicable to the basic users - the other 17 columns are only used for advanced users, and for basic users they all just contain a value of `null`.

Is this an OK setup? Would it be more efficient to, say, split the two kinds of users into two different tables, or put all the extra fields that advanced users have in a separate table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's better to have the *right* amount of tables - this may be more or less, depending on your needs.

To your specific case, you should always start with third normal form and only revert to lesser forms when absolutely necessary (such as for performance) and only when you understand the consequences.

An attribute (column) belongs in a table if it is dependent on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key (so help me, Codd).

It's arguable whether your other 17 columns depend on the key in your user table but I would be separating them anyway just for the space saving.

Have your basic user table with the twelve columns (including a unique key of some sort) and your advanced user table with the other columns, and also that key so you can tie the rows from each together.

You *could* go even further and have a one to many relationship if your use case is that users can have any of the 17 attributes independent of each other but that doesn't seem to be what you've described.

Comment: "so help me, Codd", nice one!

Comment: @cularis, I wish I could claim credit for it but, alas, no. It predates my use by quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its better to split up this table but not in two Its better to split in three table

User Table-
  Contain common property of both user and Adavace user

```
UserID(PK)
UserName
```

Basic user -
  Contains basic user property and have use primary key of user table and foreign key

```
USerID(FK) - from user table 
BasicUsedetail
```

Advance user-
    Contains Advance user property and have use primary key of user table and foreign key

```
USerID(FK) - from user table
AdvanceUsedetail
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

If the number of columns is large, then it will be more efficient to create two tables as you describe as you will not be reserving space for 17 columns which end up holding null.

You can always tack a view on the front which combines both tables, so your application code could be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's valid and more efficient to use 'single table per class hierarchy' in terms of speed to retrieve data but if you insert a BasicUser, it will reserve 17 columns per tuple just for nothing. This case is is so frequent that it is [provided by ORMs such as Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168). Using this approach you avoid a **join** between tables which may be expensive depending the case.
The bad thing is that in case your design needs to scale in terms of types of users, you will need to add additional columns which many of them will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it won't matter much, but if you got many many users and only a few of them are advanced user, it might be better to split. To my knowledge there are not exact rules of when to split and when not.